# Iterator for Matrix Native class class

Tags: c++

I wrote my own Matrix class with such fields (you can't use STL containers in it)

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T *data = nullptr;
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
```

I also made an iterator for this class:

```
public:
        class Iterator
        {
            friend Matrix;

        private:
            T *curr;

        public:
            Iterator() : curr(nullptr) {}

            Iterator(Matrix *matrix) : curr(matrix->data) {}

            ~Iterator() = default;
            ......
Iterator begin()
        {
            Iterator it(this);
            std::cout << *it.curr << std::endl;
            return it;
        }

        Iterator end()
        {
            Iterator it(this);
            /*Iterator it(this->data + rows * cols);
            if (it == nullptr)
            {
                return it;
            }*/

            return it;
        }
```

How can I properly write an end() method that would return the next element after the last one? I understand that using address arithmetic you can get the latter, but how can I do it in my code?

Comment: Make the `Iterator` constructor take a `T*` instead and store that. Then you only have to supply `data` to the `begin()` iterator and `data + size` to the `end()` iterator. If it's only supposed to iterate over the rows, store the column count too to be able to step rows.

Comment: I don't really understand how it should look like. Do you mean make the constructor like this: Iterator(T* other) : curr(other)?

Comment: Yes. Do you want the iterator to iterate over every element in the matrix or just the rows?

Comment: To iterate over each element in the matrix. And also for the iterator to be able to change the elements of the matrix

Comment: And I did the right thing, now my end() method points to the next element after the last one (I looked at what value is there - the number 0)

Comment: Ok, I added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you let the iterator take a `T*` as argument. You can then supply `data` to the `begin()` iterator and `data + rows * cols` to the `end()` iterator.

Example:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Matrix {
private:
    T* data = nullptr;
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;

public:
    Matrix(size_t Rows, size_t Cols)
        : data{new T[Rows * Cols]}, rows{Rows}, cols{Cols} {}
    Matrix(const Matrix&) = delete;
    Matrix(Matrix&&) = delete;
    ~Matrix() { delete[] data; }

    class iterator {
    private:
        T* curr;                       // store a T*

    public:
        iterator(T* t) : curr{t} {}    // take a T* and store it

        iterator& operator++() { ++curr; return *this; }
        bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const { return curr == rhs.curr; }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const { return !(curr == rhs.curr); }
        T& operator*() { return *curr; }
        T* operator->() { return curr; }
    };

    iterator begin() { return {data}; }             // begin() takes data
    iterator end() { return {data + rows * cols}; } // end() takes data + rows *cols
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3n55hY15P)

---

However, you don't need to implement an iterator yourself for this. You can simply use pointers:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Matrix {
private:
    T* data = nullptr;
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;

public:
    Matrix(size_t Rows, size_t Cols)
        : data{new T[Rows * Cols]}, rows{Rows}, cols{Cols} {}
    Matrix(const Matrix&) = delete;
    Matrix(Matrix&&) = delete;
    ~Matrix() { delete[] data; }

    using iterator = T*;        // iterator is now simply a T*

    iterator begin() { return data; }
    iterator end() { return data + rows * cols; }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And two small questions. If I want to loop through the matrix with while(it.begin() != matrix.end()) it++, then it outputs the correct data first, and then some strange ones, what's wrong? And the second question, what should the method look like that will allow us to change elements in the matrix using an iterator?

Comment: I'm sorry, I figured out the first question, only the second one has difficulties

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко You can change the elements in the matrix with any of the two iterator types in my example. If you look in the demo, the first loop is actually assigning values to the dereferenced iterator. A manual loop: `for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) *it = 123;` works just as well. [Extra demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vxncaWr6G)